# How to continue while-loop when no input is detected?

Tags: python, input, while-loop, continue

How do I continue with the while loop if nothing was inputted?

I want to make my cursor move randomly every 1 second, and end the program when I input "stop".

[Here is my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHXwn.png)

Right now it only moves once then stops, it does pop up the message box when I input "stop" though.

I tried to put continue but that didn't work.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text -- but if you're using `input()` to get text, be aware that as soon as you call `input()` your entire program will stop what it's doing until the user enters something.  You might want to use something like the `keyboard` library (or maybe `pyautogui` has a function for this, idk) to detect individual key presses without putting everything else on pause.